# Process wizard indicator on Windows phone

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, design-patterns, wizard, windows-phone-7

I'm designing a 4 step process on windows phone porting from iOS. The process has 4 steps in it, with multiple different micro-processes on each screen. Can anyone point me to an example pattern on windows phone where step indicators are used and the process has to be linear.

Just a note that it has to be as close as native as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By "process" I assume you mean screens/pages that require the user to fill in information? The "Getting Started" setup process for the OS itself is probably as native as you could get (I'm not sure how WP7's setup process is, as that's what you tagged, but WP8 should be what you're looking for). I don't recall it having an indicator, though. When you upgrade your phone it just has "Step x of y" below the progress bar.

The only app I can really think of that has more than one screen when you launch it is [Microsoft Xim](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/microsoft-xim/3627bc99-5f9d-4bbd-bb87-69eead70e28d), but that's just a welcome slideshow.